# Regex in @CucumberOptions instead of full filename

Tags: java, regex, cucumber

In my automated web-app test i have over 20 different test runners.
Each one of them is linked to cucumber feature file.
I'm using the rerun plugin to rerun failed scenario after all tests.

This is my RerunTest.java class:

```html
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"@target/teamEvaluationRerun.txt","@target/applicationRerun.txt", "@target/coeditorRerun.txt", "@target/decisionRerun.txt",
        "@target/expertRerun.txt","@target/expertZORerun.txt","@target/formalEvaluationCardRerun.txt","@target/formalEvaluationRerun.txt",
        "@target/meritEvaluationCardRerun.txt","@target/meritEvaluationRerun.txt","@target/profileRerun.txt", "@target/registerRerun.txt","@target/permissionsRerun.txt",
        "@target/notesRerun.txt","@target/tagsRerun.txt","@target/applicationTagsRerun.txt","@target/loginRerun.txt","@target/teamEvaluationCardRerun.txt","@target/programsFootersAndHeadersRerun.txt",
        "@target/attachmentsRerun.txt", "@target/profileExpertTagsRerun.txt", "@target/profileExpertBasicInfoRerun.txt", "@target/profileExpertSubmittedAppRerun.txt", "@target/profileExpertReviewedAppRerun.txt",
        "@target/profileExpertRecommendedAppRerun.txt", "@target/lossOfPermissionsToKOZ.txt", "@target/lossOfPermissionsToKOM.txt","@target/resetPasswordRerun.txt", "@target/footer.txt",
        "@target/expertListRerun.txt"},
        plugin = {"json:target/json","rerun:target/rerun.txt","io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm"})
public class _RerunTest {
}
```

This file is hard to maintain, because of direct path to rerun txt files generated from test runners, any change or typo in one of 25 filenames will throw

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file or directory: D:\selenide_cucumber\target\*.txt
```

My question is: is it possible to use regex - like @target/*Rerun.txt instead of direct path to my rerun txt files?

Comment: I assume you have multiple runners because you want to run in parallel? Cucumber supports parallel execution since v4.

Comment: No, i have other reasons to multiple test runners, and i cannot change this